# I would like to ask how can I improve my code in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

```
SELECT userinfo.NAME
    ,MONTH
    ,YEAR
    ,(
        SELECT FORMAT((min(checkinout.checktime)), "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
        FROM checkinout
        WHERE checktype = "i"
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "dd") = (tbldays.days)
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "am/pm") = ("am")
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "mmmm") = MONTH
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "yyyy") = YEAR
        ) AS TIMEIN_AM
    ,(
        SELECT FORMAT((max(checkinout.checktime)), "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
        FROM checkinout
        WHERE checktype = "o"
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "dd") = (tbldays.days)
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "am/pm") = ("am")
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "mmmm") = MONTH
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "yyyy") = YEAR
        ) AS TIMEOUT_AM
    ,(
        SELECT FORMAT((min(checkinout.checktime)), "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
        FROM checkinout
        WHERE checktype = "i"
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "dd") = (tbldays.days)
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "am/pm") = ("pm")
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "mmmm") = MONTH
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "yyyy") = YEAR
        ) AS TIMEIN_PM
    ,(
        SELECT FORMAT((max(checkinout.checktime)), "hh:mm:ss AMPM")
        FROM checkinout
        WHERE checktype = "o"
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "dd") = (tbldays.days)
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "am/pm") = ("pm")
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "mmmm") = MONTH
            AND format(checkinout.checktime, "yyyy") = YEAR
        ) AS TIMEOUT_PM
FROM checkinout
    ,userinfo
    ,tbldays
WHERE userinfo.userid = checkinout.userid
    AND userinfo.NAME = NAME_
GROUP BY tbldays.days
    ,userinfo.NAME
    ,checkinout.checktime
ORDER BY tbldays.days;
```

Checkinout for the table of time, then Userinfo for the table of General information, then tbldays for the table of days from 1 to 31

Comment: I need to improve the performance of my query. Please Help Thank you

Comment: Can you supply some examples of the contents of each table?  And also required output?